# On Click Listener Inside a Handler

Tags: android, android-studio, handler, onclicklistener

I have a `Handler` in my Loading Activity that delays my `Intent` to next Activity (which works perfectly).

What I want to do is, after the delay ends I want to have an on Click Listener that covers all the screen, but it's not working!
I've tried public void `OnClick` and `View.onClickListener` none of them work inside the `Handler`

How can i fix this?

My Handler code:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animin, R.anim.animout);
            final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(LoadingActivity.this, StartActivity.class);
            LoadingActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
            LoadingActivity.this.finish();
        }
    }, 6000);
}
```

Comment: If you want a click listener **after** the delay ends, wouldn't it need to be inside your `StartActivity`?

Comment: i dont see any onclick

Comment: @JimRhodes No! i want the "LOADING" text to change to "CLICK TO START" and when the user click anywhere on screen it goes to StartActivity

Comment: @JimRhodes i can do the text changing but i'm have troubles with the click listener

Comment: Can you post the layout for your Loading Activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That what you want is to start the activity in the click of the screen but just after th delay??

Then you should set the listener in the handler :

```
    setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);
    final View mScreen = findViewById(R.id.whole_layout);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animin, R.anim.animout);
                    final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(LoadingActivity.this, StartActivity.class);
                    LoadingActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                    LoadingActivity.this.finish();
                }
            });
        }
    }, 6000);
```

mylayout.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/whole_layout"
    android:clickeable="true"
    ...>
       <!-- your content -->
</LinearLayout>
```

You can use the layout's type that you wish

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty view that matches the layout of the screen and then setup logic to show/hide the view when appropiate?